# matching - and commas

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate given input based on these parameters
There is 1 condition that I am not able to figure out how to validate

I cannot have two dashes without a comma // 123-455-908 is invalid
and I am not able to add the condition for that in Reg

I have this regular expression

```
/^([0-9]+[-,]{0,1})*$/
```

and this is my code

```
let regexp, x, y
 regexp = /^([0-9]+[-,]{0,1})*$/
 x = "123,,"
regexp.test(x)
```

These are allowed :

> 123-234,456
>   123-345
>   123,456
>   12
>   1

These are not allowed :

> 123--234
>   123-345-456
>   123,,
>   123,,455
>   -123-34
>   ,123

anything that has anything other than number, dashes or commas is not allowed

These are some examples and I hope you get the point

Any help on this will be appreciated

Comment: Can you list some examples of strings you want to match?

Comment: I edited the question to add some examples of valid and invalid

Comment: Why not just use a count of the number of dashes and commas instead of regex? Or just split it into multiple regex

Comment: Are the strings "123-234,123-234" and "123-1" allowed?

Comment: @ZsoltGyöngyösi yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way with starting `^` and ending `$` boundary, [REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/fsp3FS/17)

```
^\d{1,}(?:-|,)?(?:\d+,?\d+)?$
```

```js
const regex = /^\d{1,}(?:-|,)?(?:\d+,?\d+)?$/gmi;
const str = `123--234
123-345-456
123,,
123,,455
-123-34
,123 

123-234,456
123-345
123,456
12
1`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }

  // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
  m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
    console.log(`Found match: ${match}`);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
^(\d{1,3}-)?\d{1,3}(,(\d{1,3}-)?\d{1,3})*$
```

`(\d{1,3}-)?\d{1,3}` validates one instance of a code, while `(,(\d{1,3}-)?\d{1,3})*` handles repetition.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is just me, but I feel it is easier to break a regexp down into smaller parts when trying to validate a string for multiple requirements.

One **pro** of doing it this way is that each regular expression becomes super simplified
But then this brings on a **con** which is you have more regular expressions in your code.

```js
let tests = [
'123-234,456',
'123-345',
'123,456',
'12',
'1',
'123--234',
'123-345-456',
'123,,',
'123,,455',
'-123-34',
',123',
'abc-123',
'a,b,c',
'abc']

function evaluate(str) {
  // Remove anything that isn't a number, ',' or '-' 
  // they will be the same length nothing was removed
  if(str.replace(/[^0-9,-]/g, '') != str) return false
  // Make sure there is no more than one '-'
  if((str.match(/-/g) || []).length > 1) return false
  // Make sure there is no more than one ','
  if((str.match(/,/g) || []).length > 1) return false
  // Make sure the string doesn't start with a ','
  if(str.match(/^,/) != null) return false

  // All tests have passed return true as it is a valid string
  return true
}

tests.forEach(i => console.log("Valid:", evaluate(i), i))
```